# ElasticSearch inconsistent wildcard search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a strange issue with my wildcard search. I've created an index with the following mapping:
[image]

I have the following document there:

[image]

When I'm performing the following query, I'm getting the document:

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard" : { "email" :  "*asdasd*"  }
  },
  "size": "10",
  "from": 0
}
```

But when I'm doing the next request, I'm not getting anything:

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard" : { "email" :  "*one-v*"  }
  },
  "size": "10",
  "from": 0
}
```

Can you please explain the reason for it?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch uses a [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) if no analyzer is specified. Assuming that the `email` field is of `text` type, so `"asdasd@one-v.co.il"` will get tokenized into

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "asdasd",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "one",
      "start_offset": 7,
      "end_offset": 10,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "v.co.il",
      "start_offset": 11,
      "end_offset": 18,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

**Now, when you are doing a wildcard query on the `email` field, then it will search for the tokens, created above. Since there is no token that matches `one-v`, you are getting empty results for the second query.**

It is better to use a `keyword` field for wildcard queries. If you have not explicitly defined any index mapping then you need to add `.keyword` to the `email` field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after the `email` field).

Modify your query as shown below

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "email.keyword": "*one-v*"
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67688032",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "email": "asdasd@one-v.co.il"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Otherwise you need to change the data type of the email field from `text` to `keyword` type

Comment: The odd thing that it was a keyword before, and I've found an answer that says that wildcard does not work on keywords only on text.
I should have tested before changing the type. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how **text fields are saved**. By default standard analyzer is used.

This is an example from the documentation which fits your case too :

The text "The 2 QUICK Brown-Foxes jumped over the lazy dog's bone." is broken into terms
[ the, 2, quick, brown, foxes, jumped, over, the, lazy, dog's, bone ].

As you can see Brown-foxes is not a single token. The same will go for one-v, it will break into one and v.